# Zabbix network discovery: matching against several received values

Tags: zabbix

Suppose I have a discovery rule that:

- Gets **model number** via SNMP
- Gets **system.uname** via the agent

Suppose I now want to create an action with the following condition:

```
Received value contains X456
AND
Received value contains Linux
```

Will that work? It seems that Zabbix may compare the first received value (let's say from the SNMP command) with Linux, which will not match. And then the whole condition will fail?

I see this in the documention: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...ion/conditions

> Service checks in a discovery rule, which result in discovery events,
>   do not take place simultaneously. Therefore, if multiple values are
>   configured for Service type, Service port or Received value conditions
>   in the action, they will be compared to one discovery event at a time,
>   but not to several events simultaneously. As a result, actions with
>   multiple values for the same check types may not be executed
>   correctly.

Is there a reliable way to do the above two conditions?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the debug output of the Discoverer process, I now understand that the above will not work. That is because the discovery events (agent and snmp in this case) will fire one by one -- not at the same time. As a result, only one of those conditions will be true. I.e., either the received value will be X456 or it will be Linux.